# Breaking one’s word to God

Tags: halacha, repentance-teshuvah

When someone wishes to repent it’s standard practice to ask HaShem for forgiveness while assuring Him that you won’t repeat the sin. But what if that person slips up & repeats the sin, is it considered that he lied to HaShem or broke an oath?

Comment: If you were sincere when promising not to repeat the sin, then it can't be a lie. If you didn't take a vow when promising not to repeat, then it can't be breaking an oath. The *yetzer hara* is trying to make you feel bad for failing again, instead keep repenting and trying your best!

Comment: Your question is too sentimental and non-Halachic. Halachicly speaking, that would be "is assuring G-d that you won't sin considered an oath". If yes - you broke an oath and follow the "doing another Teshuvah upon breaking an oath" if it's not - you're good.